# AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

The error occurs when looping through a tuple and inserting data into a MySQL Database 
In earlier segments of the code I have selected multiple FilmID's from a database and wish to reinsert the FilmID into a different table in the database. I am using the MySQL.Connector module for python and I am running into the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 179, in to_mysql
    return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 417, in _process_params
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 417, in <listcomp>
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 181, in to_mysql
    raise TypeError("Python '{0}' cannot be converted to a "
TypeError: Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Z:\My Files\Student My Documents\A Level\Computing\NEA\nea2.py", line 170, in <lambda>
    button1 = tk.Button(window, text="Start Personality Quiz?", command=lambda: menu("1"), width=18)
  File "Z:\My Files\Student My Documents\A Level\Computing\NEA\nea2.py", line 17, in menu
    PersonalityQuiz()
  File "Z:\My Files\Student My Documents\A Level\Computing\NEA\nea2.py", line 82, in PersonalityQuiz
    mycursor.execute(LinkInsert,vals)
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 539, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\Users\lupin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 421, in _process_params
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

The code where the error I believe to be is below:

```
    import mysql.connector
    import datetime
    
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="username",
    password="",
    database="database name")
    
    sql = "SELECT FilmID FROM Movies"

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    firstname=input
    surname=input

    SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, Surname) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    vals = (firstname,surname)
    mycursor.execute(SQLinsert,vals)
    mydb.commit()

    UserID = mycursor.lastrowid

    for i in myresult:
        LinkInsert = "INSERT INTO userlink VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        vals = (UserID, i, datetime.datetime)
        mycursor.execute(LinkInsert,vals)
        mydb.commit()
```

I initially thought that this was a error with the datetime so I tried ommiting it only to get the same result. I hope what I have given is sufficient as this is my first time on stack overflow. If anyone has any solutions to my problem I am very grateful. 
Thank you very much, Lupin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because variable "i" is passed as a tuple in other words when you loop in the list "myresult" the value of "i" is `(*)` where * is the value of id.

So you have to select the index of the first item:

```
vals = (UserID, i[0], datetime.datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the `vals` tuple which is not converted to any MySQL type.

So you can pass tuple in `executemany` like this :

```
mycursor.executemany(LinkInsert,vals)
```